# Weird result in comparing dates in PHP

Tags: php, datetime, strtotime

I have a simple function that counts number of weeks since a given date. The "active" week contains dates within a range. Each week start from a saturday and end on the next saturday. This was working fine untill today: 01/10/2021, instead of returning a positive number, the function now returns -1.

Here's the code:

```
public function getActiveWeek(){
    //1. Get the current date
    $current_date = date('d-m-Y H:i:s'); //now GTM+1

    //2.Define starting and ending week range
    $start_week = "18-09-2021 00:00:00";
    //Now, to get $end_week, we add 7 days 00h 00m 00s to $start_week
    $end_week = date('d-m-Y H:i:s', strtotime($start_week) + 604800);
    //3. Check if the current date is between the starting and ending week range
    $current_week = 0;
    if ($current_date >= $start_week && $current_date <= $end_week) {
        echo "Current date is between the starting and ending week range";
        $current_week = $current_week;
    } else if ($current_date > $end_week) {
        echo "Current date is after the ending week range";
        //We count the weeks since $start_week
        $weeks_count = $this->getWeeksBetweenDates($start_week, $current_date);
        $current_week = $weeks_count; //was previously : $current_week + 1;
    } else if ($current_date < $start_week) {
        echo "Current date is before the starting week range"; 
        echo $current_date . " < " . $start_week;
        $current_week = $current_week - 1;
    } else {
        throw new Exception("Some errors in getActiveWeek() function.");
    }

    return $current_week;
}
```

Now the problem is condition `$current_date > $end_week` is evaluated to false which leads to the next condition be evaluated to true (`$current_date < $start_week`). Changing `$current_date` to, say, "26-09-2021 00:00:00" works perfectly and the function returns 1.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks for your help.

Comment: You're comparing strings, and 01 comes before 18. You'd have better luck comparing [DateTime objects](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php)

Comment: you need to convert $start_week to a date object or timestamp to be able to compare it, currently your just comparing a string

Comment: Tried with: ```$start_week = date('d-m-Y', strtotime("18-09-2021 00:00:00"));``` still the same.

Comment: `strtotime()` expects the date to be in the format `YYYY-MM-DD`, not `DD-MM-YYYY`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was easy. I had to convert `$start_week` to date object and importantly the format was the issue as well. The below works solved my problem:

```
$start_week = date('Y/m/d H:i:s', strtotime($starting_date));
```

Comment: Unfortunately `$starting_date` remains undefined (as well in the question), therefore it is hard to read/understand the code. Please consider to add a bit more context (e.g. example values) so that future user can more easily understand _why_ this solution did work in your case so that they can easily grasp if it is helpful for their case (or not). Thanks a lot!

Comment: `date()` does not return an object, it returns a formatted string. You've made the format it uses more easily sortable, but you should still be using actual [`DateTime`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime) objects as they handle time zones, leap time, and other edge cases much more gracefully.